# How to fix the "Incompatible types: 'PPointer' and 'Pointer'" Delphi compiler error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, graphics32

When building a program that uses the **Graphics32** library (the old **1.9.1** version) with Delphi XE4 (targeting Win32, if it matters), I got the following compiler error:

> [dcc32 Error] GR32_LowLevel.pas(1240): E2010 Incompatible >types: 'PPointer' and 'Pointer'

Which is produced by this line:
`Registry.RegisterBinding(FID_FILLLONGWORD, @@FillLongWord);`

Where `RegisterBinding` is defined as:

```
procedure RegisterBinding(FunctionID: Integer; BindVariable: PPointer);
```

And `FillLongword` is defined as:

```
var
  FillLongword: procedure(var X; Count: Cardinal; Value: Longword);
```

How to resolve the compiler error? To my eyes it seems that the syntax is correct, isn't `@@` means 'pointer of pointer', which is `PPointer`?
Thanks.

Comment: `@@` means address of procedural variable. Documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Procedural_Types_(Delphi)

Comment: Which version of graphics32 are you using? Are you pulling the latest from the repo?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, updated the Q, it's the old gr32 1.9.1 version, not the latest repos. Because I'm using Angus's old `GR32_Objects`

Comment: I wonder why is it a PPointer and not a TFillLongword, or possibly a TFillValue, or perhaps TDoSomething....

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, because `RegisterBinding` accepts different definitions of procedure/functions - in other words, functions passed as `BindVariable' might have different parameters.

Comment: Upgraded to the latest Grapics32 github repository and there is no such a compilation error with it. However, I guess the original question is still valid as a Delphi programming question, so I'll keep this post.